# Single screen application without bottom navigation bar

Tags: react-native

I've analyzed the needs of my application and decided I can more efficiently develop it with mobile friendly components on the web and present it via a web view in an app.

I need permissions to access camera and gallery (to take photos / videos, and upload photos / videos).

Basically, a single-screen app with a webview presenting the site with mobile-friendly components and the above permissions.

This is my current app.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import {
  createStackNavigator,
  createBottomTabNavigator,
  createAppContainer,
} from 'react-navigation';
//import createStackNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer in our project
import HomeScreen from './pages/HomeScreen';
import { Constants, Location, Camera, Permissions } from 'expo';

const ProfileStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    //Definition of Navigaton from home screen
    HomeScreen: { screen: HomeScreen },
  },
  {
    //For React Navigation 2.+ change defaultNavigationOptions->navigationOptions
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      //Header customization of the perticular Screen
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: 'orange',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#FFFFFF',
      title: '',
      //Header title
    },
  }
);

const App = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    HomeScreen: { screen: HomeScreen },
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        let IconComponent = Ionicons;
        let iconName;
        if (routeName === 'HomeScreen') {
          iconName = `ios-information-circle${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
        }
        return <IconComponent name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
      },
    }),
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: 'orange',
      inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
    },
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(App);
```

and './pages/HomeScreen':

```
//This is an example code for Bottom Navigation//
import React, {Component} from 'react';
//import react in our code.
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, WebView } from 'react-native';
//import all the basic component we have used

export default class ProfileScreen extends React.Component {
  //Profile Screen to show from Open profile button
  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        source={{uri: 'https://mobilesite'}}
        style={{marginTop: 20}}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

So far, the site opens on a single screen as expected, but there's a bottom navigation bar present; I'd also like to preferably hide the top bar if possible too as I've accounted for that in a mobile-friendly header on the mobile site as well.

Also, via the mobile web codebase, I'm utilizing `<input type="file" />` for uploading. Is this compatible with React Native `Permissions`?

Answer (score 0):

You're using `createBottomTabNavigator()` and passing the resulting navigator to your `createAppContainer()` which will create a bottom tab navigator.

If you pass a StackNavigator (via `createStackNavigator()` which you use for `ProfileStack`) to the `createAppContainer()` it'll render the stack as opposed to the bottom tab navigator which is what you want.

To remove the header altogether you can use `headerMode: 'none'` in the `navigationOptions` param.

You can see a basic version of what you want here (sans the lack of a header) in the [React Navigation docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/hello-react-navigation.html).